How can I resolve a Syntax error?
I've got the below equation in the New Formula (Text) field for Account within Object Manager's Fields & Relationships. All of the lines come back with No Syntax Errors when I 'Check Syntax' with each line independently.
However, when I put them all together (see the below) the following error comes up:

"Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3,
received 4"

I'm not sure how to proceed. Please may you advise? That would be greatly appreciated:
IF( ( Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY() ) <= 14, "", 

IF( ( Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY() ) > 14, "",

IF(ISPICKVAL(contact_do_not_contact__c, "Contact"),"","Contact",

IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(contact_do_not_contact__c)),"⚪️","-"))))

For extra context, what is the intention of this field?
If Contact is selected from the picklist, then Do Not Contact Review Date is not required. If Do Not Contact is selected from the picklist, then a Do Not Contact Review Date is required. Another possibility is that these fields start off blank for accounts which have already been saved/ created prior to this field being added. With regard to colour indicators:

IF Contact then show 
IF Contact/ Do Not Contact selected then show ⚪️
IF Do Not Contact and the Do Not Contact Review Date is <= 14 days from TODAY, then display 
IF No Do Not Contact and the Do Not Contact Review Date is > 14 days from TODAY, then display 

Thank you!!


The last part, starting from the third IF statement, isn't parenthesized correctly. There's actually four parameters here.
IF(ISPICKVAL(contact_do_not_contact__c, "Contact"),"","Contact",
// This IF statement ends up being the fourth parameter to the line before
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(contact_do_not_contact__c)),"⚪️","-"))))

Second, the IF statement conditions are incorrect. You should check if the Contact value is selected first, then the do not contact value:
IF(ISPICKVAL(contact_do_not_contact__c, "Contact"),"",
  IF(ISPICKVAL(contact_do_not_contact__c, "Do Not Contact",
    IF(Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY() <= 14, "", ""),
    "⚪️"
  )
)

Note that we can make the formula even more legible with a CASE statement:
CASE(
  contact_do_not_contact__c,
  "Contact", "",
  "Do Not Contact", IF(Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY() <= 14, "", ""),
  "⚪️"
)


Thank you sfdcfox for your explanation of how to get to a working formula as well as for sharing one! This works very efficiently.

The error shows due to an extra parameter in one of your IF statements.
This one: IF(ISPICKVAL(contact_do_not_contact__c, "Contact"),"","Contact",
IF function requires exactly three parameters: condition, value if true, and value if false.
IF((Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY()) <= 14, "", 
        IF((Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY()) > 14, "",
                IF(ISPICKVAL(contact_do_not_contact__c, "Contact"),"",
                        IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(contact_do_not_contact__c)),"⚪️","-")
                )
        )
)


Thank you for your helpful explanation Tushar. I appreciate it!

Formatting your formula according to best practice helps make it easier to spot errors.
Basically, put almost every function call onto their own lines, and indent.
IF( 
    (Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY()) <= 14, 
    "", 
    IF(
        (Do_not_contact_review_date__c - TODAY()) > 14, 
        "",
        IF(
            ISPICKVAL(contact_do_not_contact__c, "Contact"),
            "",
            "Contact",
            IF(
                ISBLANK(TEXT(contact_do_not_contact__c)),
                "⚪️",
                "-"
            )
        )
    )
)

The syntax error here is that you have "Contact", after the green circle in the penultimate IF(). That's where you're trying to give 4 parameters instead of 3.
Beyond that, however, you have a semantic error. It's impossible for you to get to the green circle or the gray circle parts of your nested IF()s because the first two conditions (<= 14 and > 14) completely cover all scenarios.
You can only get into the second IF() when the review date is strictly greater than 14. You will never get into the "else" part of that second IF() as written. You'll need to re-arrange this formula so that you're doing the checks against contact_do_not_contact__c first.

Thank you for your helpful explanation Derek. That's great advice to format my formula into best practice - I will do this going forward!
